# yii возвращает неправильный url

Tags: yii, .htaccess, apache2

Есть проблема

```
var_dump(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getUrl());
```

выводит  url //site/index  а должен /site/index. Откуда берется еще один слеш. Может нужно настроить сервер? Использую apache2 на VPS.

Конфигурация apache

```
 <Directory /var/www/ua>

     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.php    
    Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

    Require all granted

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            <IfModule mod_mime.c>
                    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
            </IfModule>
            <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
                    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
            </FilesMatch>

            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag track_vars On
            php_flag register_globals Off
            php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off

            #php_value include_path .
            #php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
            #php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/
        </IfModule>

</Directory>
```

конфигурация в .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +Indexes
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

 Require all granted


 # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 # otherwise forward it to index.php
 RewriteRule . index.php

  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
```

Comment: Скорее всего это действительно решается настройками сервера (вероятно, идет не очень корректный rewrite со стороны апача), но глядя несколько раз в код CHttpRequest - поведение этой штуки просто невозможно предсказать. Если есть возможность взять другой фреймворк - берите другой, Yii 1.х давно пора на покой.

Comment: в yii 2 он вообще с ума сойдет от настройки бэка и фронта)))

Comment: @des1roer думаю, мы все тут хотели бы видеть комментарии по существу.

Comment: @Etki спасибо за совет, но уже сайт написан на Yii 1.1.5 версии, поэтому нужно как-то решить эту проблему. Вот интересно как правильно настроить rewrite

Comment: @modelfak приведите текущую конфигурацию

Comment: @Etki Добавил в вопрос конфигурацию

Comment: @modelfak нужна конфигурация mod_rewrite (вероятнее всего, она в .htaccess)

Comment: @Etki добавил все что в .htaccess

Comment: попробуйте спросить непосредственно у `php`, а не у функций-обёрток. примерно такой командой: `file_put_contents('/tmp/filename.txt', print_r($_SERVER, true, FILE_APPEND));`. она при каждом вызове будет добавлять в указанный файл содержимое массива `$_SERVER`. поместите её где-нибудь в начале «корневого» `index.php`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо! нашел в чем баг - вся проблема в REQUEST_URI , он возвращает  двойной слеш '"//" как его настроить на сервере может?

Comment: если вы обращаетесь по *url* `/site/index`, то ваш браузер перенаправляется на `//site/index`? сколько раз при этом выполняется предложенная мною команда? если больше одного, сравните значения *всех* переменных.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, но я решил уже проблему так - я использую yii, нашел глобальный метод который возвращает REQUEST_URI  и в нем просто вырезаю слеш, но все равно хотелось бы решить ее на уровне сервера. Когда я ввожу /site/index то меня по нему и перенаправляет, дело не в mod_rewrite а что-то в настройках сервера конфигурации